# Spring Cloud Stream and Kafka Integration Error Handling

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-kafka

I am trying to create a Spring Boot application with Spring Cloud Stream and Kafka integration. I created a sample Topic in Kafka with 1 partition and have published to the topic from the Spring Boot application created based on the directions given here

http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/1.0.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/index.html

and

https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2016/04/event-driven-microservices-spring-cloud-stream/

Spring Boot App -

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication {

    private static final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(MyApplication.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Kafka Producer Class

```
@Service
@EnableBinding(Source.class)
public class MyProducer {

    private static final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(MyProducer.class);

    @Bean
    @InboundChannelAdapter(value = Source.OUTPUT, poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "10000", maxMessagesPerPoll = "1"))
    public MessageSource<TimeInfo> timerMessageSource() {
        TimeInfo t = new TimeInfo(new Timestamp(new Date().getTime())+"","Label");
        MessageBuilder<TimeInfo> m = MessageBuilder.withPayload(t);
        return () -> m.build();
    }

    public static class TimeInfo{

        private String time;
        private String label;

        public TimeInfo(String time, String label) {
            super();
            this.time = time;
            this.label = label;
        }

        public String getTime() {
            return time;
        }

        public String getLabel() {
            return label;
        }

    }
}
```

All is working well except for when I want to handle exceptions.

If the Kafka Topic went down, I can see the ConnectionRefused exception being thrown in the log files for the app, but the retry logic built in seems to be going at retrying continuously without stopping!

There is no exception thrown at all for me to handle and do further exception processing. I have read through the Producer options and the Binder options for Kafka in the Spring Cloud Stream documentation above and I cannot see any customization options possible to get this exception thrown above all the way for me to capture.

I am new to Spring Boot / Spring Cloud Stream / Spring Integration (which seems to be the underlying implementation to the cloud stream project).

Is there anything else you guys know to get this exception cascaded to my Spring Cloud Stream app?

Comment: Hi Satya,  I am looking something like this in  my application. Do you have any suggestion or links which would help me? Thanks

Comment: @ULLASK - Back when this happened, I had rolled back my spring-cloud-stream code and ended up using spring-kafka. Not sure if the recent updates to the spring-cloud-stream library allow cascading exceptions and handling them.